# How can I rewrite this PHP members only page script?

Tags: php, include

I have this code which displays specific content to logged in users. However using this I can't include other php files on the page. Is there anyway to rewrite this so I can use the include function.

```
<?php
   if($_SESSION['id'])
      echo '<div id="center" class="column">center here</div>
            <div id="left" class="column">leftbar here</div>
            <div id="right" class="column">rightbar here</div>';
   else
      echo '<h1>Staff please, <a href="index.php">login</a> 
            before accessing this page,   no access to students.</h1>';
?>
```

At the moment I can't put in where it says 'center here', 'leftbar here' and 'rightbar here' this:

```
`<?php include("center.php"); ?>`
```

I am new to all this stuff, so don't get too complicated, thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use `include`?

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk I seem to be getting syntax errors when using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly it should be like this:

```
<?php
       if($_SESSION['id'])
          echo '<div id="center" class="column">';
               include("center.php");
          echo'</div>
                <div id="left" class="column">';
              include("leftbar.php");
         echo'</div>
                <div id="right" class="column">';
             include("rightbar.php");
          echo '</div>';
       else
          echo '<h1>Staff please, <a href="index.php">login</a> 
                before accessing this page,   no access to students.</h1>';
?>
```

Comment: Getting a syntax on 'else' part of the code, the rest looks good though. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: @TomCarter There was a syntax error; try the code again.

Comment: Still get getting a syntax error on that code :/

Comment: there was indeed a syntax error but you also have to check your incude files for syntax errors. What line? what file ?